A single-symbol notation for "between (inclusive)", as in "between x_1 and x_2, inclusive"?
When $x$ is between 1 and 10, we can write $x \in [1,10]$, or we can write $1 \leq x \leq 10$. Has a single symbol ever been used instead? For example, has there been a symbol used instead of $\between$ in
"$x$ is $1 \between 10"$
to get the same meaning?

To my knowledge, no, not in any meaningful way. About the best that encapsulates a single "symbol" would be to say
$$
x \in \overline{a,b}
$$
where $\overline{a,b}$ means the same as $[a,b]$, or in some contexts just the integers in that range. It is infrequently used in my experience. [cont.]

I recall looking for a similar symbol a while back, since I was looking for something to concisely communicate "betweenness" in the same way that "$x \in [a,b]$" does, but without the stipulation that $a \le b$ or $b \le a$ being known. (It was convenient for Taylor's theorem results.) Eventually I just caved and made my own symbol though,
$$
x \in \langle!\langle a,b \rangle!\rangle
$$
Hardly the best but it's for a personal set of notes that'll almost surely never been seen by anyone else, so who cares.

I would recommend just using $x\in[1,10]$. Unfamiliar symbols will hamper understanding, and it's not even shorter than this standard notation.

@PrincessEv - Strange there's no accepted symbol for a bounded interval between $a$ and $b$ without regard to which is greater. Another option would be to underline the comma or double it. Then one could keep rounded and square brackets as required.
